# How can I handle JMS redelivery into my Camel Route, but still allow message deletion

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have a Camel Route that reads from an ActiveMQ JMS Queue, does some processing, and passes the result on to a remote destination. If the communications part of this process fails, I want to retry *indefinitely* (until the destination is "up").  I can handle this by making the route `transacted` and setting up the `redeliveryPolicy`.  The redelivery is set in both Camel (via `camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy` to reattempt the failed part of the route) and the ActiveMQConnectionFactory (via `org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy` to reattempt the entire route).

I also have a requirement that we should be able to delete an entry from the JMS queue (which I do via an application that talks to ActiveMQ via JMX), and processing should move to the next message.

The issue is that I can either allow message deletions (by setting the consumer to be `cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE`), or have the connection handle retries (by setting the consumer to be `cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER`), but not both.

Here is my current setup:

```xml
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.brokerUrl}" />
  <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="amqRedeliveryPolicy" />
  <property name="prefetchPolicy">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
      <property name="all" value="0"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
  <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" >
  <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<!-- Redelivery Policy for ActiveMQ (the Broker), so it will perform retries of the entire route -->
<bean id="amqRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
  <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
  <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="-1" />
  <property name="queue" value=">" />
</bean>

<!-- Redelivery Policy for Camel Internal, so it will retry from the part of the exchange that's failed in case of comms issues -->
<bean id="redeliveryProfile" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="2"/>
  <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="500"/>
</bean>

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<camel:camelContext id="testContext">
  <camel:routeBuilder ref="transactedRoute" />
</camel:camelContext>
```

With a very simple route:

```java
@Component
public class TransactedRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    onException(Exception.class) // we would handle comms exceptions here
      .redeliveryPolicyRef("redeliveryProfile")
      .rollback();

    from("jms:queue:myqueue?cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER")
      .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
      .bean(Bean1.class)
      .to(DESTINATION); // this could throw a comms exception
  }
}
```

With this setup, the route reads from `jms:queue:myqueue`, and in the case of a Comms exception, Camel internally retries the route from `to` part twice (`redeliveryProfile`). Then after a 5-second delay the message is sent through the entire route again (`amqRedeliveryPolicy`). This continues until I stop the test.

However, if I delete the message from ActiveMQ, it continues to be processed by the route, despite it no longer being in the queue.

If I change the consumer to be:

```
from("jms:queue:myqueue?cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE")
```

I can now delete the message from ActiveMQ and the route stops processing it... but `amqRedeliveryPolicy` is ignored, the message is retried immediately (no 5-second delay) and after 6 attempts (the default for AMQ) it is put into the Dead Letter Queue.

So, is there a way to achieve both by modifying my configuration?

Or have I completely missed the point somewhere along the lines?

Comment: I did some more playing around and found that setting the `acknowledgementModeName` to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` on the `to(...)` of the route meant that I got continual retries, with message deletion recognised, but the message was redelivered immediately (no 5s delay) after the Camel-internal redelivery.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like a bad design if you need human intervention to delete a specific message on a queue via JMX.

Maybe you can let AMQ move the message to a DLQ after X number of failed attempts - redelivery forever is also a bad design. But you can increase the defaults to a higher value if 6 attempts is to little.

Then from the DLQ queue you can inspect the messages and maybe try to understand why the message failed, and you can always delete or purge the DLQ queue via JMX or other tools safely.

AMQ allows to have a DLQ per queue where you can configure it to use a DLQ prefix etc, instead of one common DLQ queue.

Comment: Yes, it is an odd design - the queue that we read from is actually user-visible (via another part of the application), and we have requirements for the user to be able to delete messages. The `to(...)` part will actually be a remote system that _could_ be down, in which case we want to retry until the destination is up, or the message is removed by the user. Basically we would rollback the transaction in the case of comms errors - I will alter my question to make that clearer.